# How to properly create a Dynamic Pivot Function in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I come back with my problem. I've been trying to create a dynamic pivot procedure but I have some trouble while creating the columns.

Example:

| TranID | Bank Name | NetAmount | Account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | StormWindBank | 23.0$ | A |
| 02 | StormWindBank | 14.0$ | B |
| 03 | StormWindBank | 00.0$ | A |
| 04 | StormWindBank | 12.0$ | B |

Result intended :

| Account | Bank Name | NetAmount | NetAmount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | StormWindBank | 23.0$ | 00.0$ |
| B | StormWindBank | 14.0$ | 12.0$ |

```
SELECT  DISTINCT [Account]
        ,[Currency]
        ,TranID
        ,[Bank Code]
        ,[Bank Name]
        ,[Client No_]
        ,[NetAmount]
        INTO #TEMP
FROM [My Table]

    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.NetAmount) 
            FROM #TEMP c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  [Account], [Bank Name], ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select  [Account],TranID, NetAmount, [Bank Name]
                from #TEMP
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(TranID)
                for NetAmount in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
```

So far, I have the result below:

| Account | Bank Name | 23.0$ | 00.0$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | StormWindBank | 1 | 2 |
| B | StormWindBank | 3 | 4 |

The 1, 2, 3, 4 are the TranID.

I'm close but I have been struggling to fix that, anyone have an idea ?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server do you have? On newer versions you can use `STRING_AGG`. Also if you have a maximum number of `NetAmount` columns then you could do a static pivot rather than a dynamic one.

Comment: @Charlieface I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to PIVOT off a derived column using `row_number()`

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = stuff( ( Select Distinct concat(',[NetAmount',row_number() over (partition by [Bank Name],[Account] order by [TranID]),']' ) 
                                      From #TEMP For XML Path('') ),1,1,'')

Set @SQL = '
Select *
 From (
        Select [Account]
              ,[Bank Name]
              ,Item  = concat(''NetAmount'',row_number() over (partition by [Bank Name],[Account] order by [TranID]) )
              ,Value = [NetAmount]
         from #TEMP
      ) src
 Pivot ( max( [Value] ) for Item in ('+ @SQL   +') ) pvt
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

```
Account Bank Name       NetAmount1  NetAmount2
A       StormWindBank   23.0$       00.0$
B       StormWindBank   14.0$       12.0$
```

Comment: You sir, are a true gentlemen !! I'm actually trying to understand why such a fit was needed. But your answer unlocked me gracefully !! Bless you :)

Comment: I will have a toast in your name John !